# MySQL How to select date after n days, n is a value present in 'duration' column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I know that we can get the date after n days using

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL n DAY)
```

But if value of n is determined from a column, what should be the query?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but have you tried just putting the column name into the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply include the column in place of *n* (After `INTERVAL`):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL `duration` DAY)
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle showing this works.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/481c23/1)